# How to display/send r plotly plots on web using plumber?

Tags: r, r-plotly, plumber

I have one plotly plot and I want to display plot on other UI such as
angular, using R Plumber.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you do it:

```
# API for experimenting with html widgets

library(plumber)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#* @apiTitle HTML widgets API

#* Return interactive plot using plotly
#* @serializer htmlwidget
#* @get /plotly
function() {
  p <- ggplot(data = diamonds,
              aes(x = cut, fill = clarity)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")

  ggplotly(p)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Source - https://github.com/blairj09/plumber-playground/blob/master/experiments/htmlwidgets-exp/plumber.R